# Wire edges and Material don't move when I move the object

Tags: modeling

I download the last version of Blender and when I transform the cube wire edges and material don't move !

But in Edit Mode it seems there are no problem !

I've make a video capture , you can see here : https://youtu.be/enj35YWyIAI

Do you know this strange problem and is there a solution ?
Thanks.

Comment: Does your system meet the requirements for Blender? https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Comment: Yes but I have only 4Gb of RAM, opengl 4.1, windows 10 and 1Gb for graphic card

Comment: Now it seems there are no problem ...

Comment: It seems that there are a similary problem with  **@Pashby** [Elijah Pashby ] (https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/93310/elijah-pashby)    [Selected mesh will not move in Object mode ] (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173982/selected-mesh-will-not-move-in-object-mode)