# Selected mesh will not move in Object mode

Tags: modeling, mesh

I just installed Blender 2.82a on my PC and found that the initial cube will not move when selected in object mode. When selected the outline turns yellow, but when I attempt to use the move command the outline turns white and moves, but leaves the cube behind. This happens even if I delete the cube and add a new mesh. If I duplicate the mesh or add other meshes, the new mesh will move but will use the other mesh as its reference. I have uninstalled and reinstalled several times to no avail. I also installed Blender 2.82a on my Wacom companion 2 and it works perfectly. I have embedded a screencast on my website that illustrates the issue. https://www.artforthismortalcoil.com/blenderscreencast

Comment: It seems the link to your screencast doesn't work, it just redirects to autodesk.com.

Comment: Thank you, I realized that and removed it. I wish I knew how to link it.

Comment: The problem is so strange because it only happens on my desktop. It makes the program useless on my desktop though, because if I can't even move the meshes, I'm stuck.

Comment: If you can find another way to upload the screencast (imgur, Google Drive, etc) that would be helpful, otherwise I'm not sure how to determine the problem.

Comment: TheTrueJard I think I figured out how to embed it into my website. Here is the link:  https://www.artforthismortalcoil.com/blenderscreencast

Comment: Oh my, that is highly unusual. Does it happen in edit mode too? Does it happen when you rotate and scale or just move?

Comment: It does the same thing with rotate and scale in Object mode, but it does seem to move, scale rotate etc in edit mode if entire mesh is selected. It also seems that the camera can move in object mode.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really know how to help with this. The only suggestion I'd have is to try a different version of Blender, maybe 2.82 or even 2.81. I'm not familiar enough with the source to know exactly what might be causing this.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for at least checking it out. Stay safe out there

Comment: wow, that is weird! Looks like the cube actually moved but that the display isn't updated. What happens when you rotate the view or change the shading mode?

Comment: wilks- I just tried to change the view and the shading mode and it does the same thing.

Comment: @ElijahPashby Then the only thing I could think of is a problem with your graphic card drivers? (but that's really a shot in the dark)

Comment: wilks- I manually updated the driver and you were right. It worked! thanks for the suggestion. I hadn't had problems with other programs so I didn't suspect that.

Comment: I experience the same issue. The object can be rotated but not moved. Even though I checked the MOVE Gjizmo, it does not show it. Additionally, the object is not linked, parented, or tracked. It is a mystery.

Answer (score -1):

I just find a way to fix it, changing to Edit mode, do anything with object (as move points of object) then come back Object mode. Everything will be fixed.